# Jmeter/Selenium scroll down in a specific area and not the entire page

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, jmeter

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to scroll down a one section only from the entire webpage. I have tried `window.scrollBy(x,y)` which works but for the entire page and not the section which I need. The scroll bar does not show up either. I am using JMeter (JS as language) and Selenium as the driver.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- `var element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('some id'))`  - locate the Web Element you want to "see"
- `WDS.browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', element)` - bring the element into the visible area

More information:

- [Element.scrollIntoView()](http://Element.scrollIntoView())
- [HTML DOM scrollIntoView Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)