# How to scroll up and down to any element using web driver sampler JMeter and java and selenium wedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am not able to scroll down a page while using JMeter with WebDriversampler and java.
I have tried below but not works for me
var element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('some id')) - locate the Web Element you want to "see"
WDS.browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', element) - bring the element into the visible area

Answer (score 0):

There is no "java" in the WebDriver Sampler, if you choose `java` from the language dropdown it means [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) which you really [shouldn't be using since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/)

For JavaScript the code you copied and pasted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71083235/2897748) should work just fine.

For [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) you need to change `var` to `def`.